# Getting the delete button to delete on a task list using pure Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I'm creating a task list, and trying to get my delete button to actually delete the task it is appended to. Still pretty new to all this, appreciate any help given.

Here's my HTML :

```
<body>
<h1>Start your list!</h1>
<div class="input">
<input type="text" id="task" placeholder="Enter new task.">
<button id="submit">Create</button>
</div>
<section id="list">
</section>
</body>
```

And here is my Javascript so far:

```
// Creating a new task
const button = document.getElementById("submit");

button.addEventListener("click", () => {
  var taskInput = document.getElementById("task").value;
  // Creating the text for list item.
  if (taskInput === "") {
    // Prevents empty list item.
    alert("You have to type a task!");
  } else {
    var listItem = document.createElement("li"); // Create li element.
    var task = document.createElement("p"); // Create p element.
    var text = document.createTextNode(taskInput); // Create text for list item.
    task.appendChild(text); // Append text to p element.
    listItem.appendChild(task); // Append p to list item.
  }
 

  // Create a delete button
  var deleteButton = document.createElement("button");
  deleteButton.innerHTML = "Delete";
  deleteButton.setAttribute("class", "btn delete");
 
  

  //Create an edit button
  var editButton = document.createElement("button");
  editButton.innerHTML = "Edit";
  editButton.setAttribute("class", "btn edit");
  editButton.setAttribute("onclick", "editThis(this)");

  //Create button section
  var buttons = document.createElement("div");
  buttons.setAttribute("class", "buttons");
  buttons.appendChild(editButton);
  buttons.appendChild(deleteButton);
  listItem.appendChild(buttons);

  //Add new list item to list
  var list = document.getElementById("list");
  list.appendChild(listItem);
});

// Delete List Item
const removeItem = document.getElementsByClassName('delete');
removeItem.addEventListener("click", "removeThis(removeItem)");

function removeThis(removeItem) {
  var parent = removeItem.parentElement.parentElement;
  parent.parentElement.removeChild(parent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`editThis` is not defined at code at Question. The second parameter to `.addEventListener()` should be a function, not a string. Also `removeItem` is a collection of elements, not a single element

```
for (let i = 0; i < removeItem.length; i++) {
  removeItem[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    removeThis(this)
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better to attach the listener as soon as you are creating the button. Look at below code

```
// Creating a new task
const button = document.getElementById("submit");

button.addEventListener("click", () => {
  var taskInput = document.getElementById("task").value;
  // Creating the text for list item.
  if (taskInput === "") {
    // Prevents empty list item.
    alert("You have to type a task!");
  } else {
    var listItem = document.createElement("li"); // Create li element.
    var task = document.createElement("p"); // Create p element.
    var text = document.createTextNode(taskInput); // Create text for list item.
    task.appendChild(text); // Append text to p element.
    listItem.appendChild(task); // Append p to list item.
  }


  // Create a delete button
  var deleteButton = document.createElement("button");
  deleteButton.innerHTML = "Delete";
  deleteButton.setAttribute("class", "btn delete");



  //Create an edit button
  var editButton = document.createElement("button");
  editButton.innerHTML = "Edit";
  editButton.setAttribute("class", "btn edit");
  editButton.setAttribute("onclick", "editThis(this)");

  //Create button section
  var buttons = document.createElement("div");
  buttons.setAttribute("class", "buttons");
  buttons.appendChild(editButton);
  buttons.appendChild(deleteButton);
  listItem.appendChild(buttons);

    deleteButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
    console.log(this);
    console.log(this.parentElement.parentElement);
    var parent = this.parentElement.parentElement;
    parent.parentElement.removeChild(parent);
  });
  //Add new list item to list
  var list = document.getElementById("list");
  list.appendChild(listItem);
});
```